# close(pipe[1]) after exec

Tags: c, pipe, exec

I got a pipe.

```
int anotherPipe[2];
make(anotherPipe);
```

Both of the following processes have access to this pipe.

Process A:

```
close(anotherPipe[0]);
dup2(anotherPipe[1], 1); //redirect stdout to pipe
execl("/usr/bin/who", "usr/bin/who", NULL);
close(anotherPipe[1]); //this is never executed
```

Process B:

```
close(anotherPipe[1]);
read(anotherPipe[0], stringbuffer, bytestoread);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
printf("checkpoint\n");
close(anotherPipe[0]);
```

The "who" command's output from execl is redirected to process B via pipe, where it is printed. But now my process B is not terminating, although the checkpoint is printed.

By 'not terminating' I mean that the following is not displayed in the terminal:

```
myusername@ubuntucomputer:~$
```

What is happening here and how is it solved?

EDIT: Solved the issue with the non-terminating process B. It terminated, but my top level process finished before A and B, so the

```
myusername@ubuntucomputer:~$
```

was printed a lot earlier. I used waitpid() and now everything is fine.

Comment: can you post the whole source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `execl()` is successful, nothing after it in the original program runs, since it replaces the contents of the process with the program you ask it to run. You need to close the pipe *before* `execl`:

```
close(anotherPipe[0]);
dup2(anotherPipe[1], 1); //redirect stdout to pipe
close(anotherPipe[1]);
execl("/usr/bin/who", "usr/bin/who", (char*)NULL);
```

Also, don't forget to case `NULL` to `(char*)` when calling `execl`. Since it's a variable-arguments function, it won't convert the type automatically.

Comment: But how can its output then be redirected into the pipe when it is closed?

Comment: Because you duplicated it to FD 1, which is still open.

Comment: Alright, but unfortunately that still does not solve my problem with the non-terminating process B.

Comment: @JohannesKlaus Then you need to provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is process B hanging? I don't see a loop, so why isn't it terminating?